# Skip metadata.drop_all metadata.create_all if schema didn't change

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If drop_all; create_all would not leave me with a schema change, I would want to skip that two lines.

How can I achieve that?

Background: I use an SQLite for caching and saving data on code changes isn't worth the effort, yet if stuff is cached and no code or db changes occurred meanwhile, I would like to keep the cached data and just use it.

Note: The question now is of academic interest as the solution "the developer has to care about migration" was accepted by my team. I would still be interested in how to detect if the actual db-schema matches the entities-derived db-schema.

Comment: So, in other words, you are asking to see if there is a way for SQLAlchemy to detect if the schema of the database it is looking at is different than the schema that would be generated if it were to create it from scratch?

Comment: Yes. If schema(entities) != schema(db): recreate_db()

Answer (score 1):

create a version table in your database that stores a version number for the schema, then check this number against a number that's in your application.

This is the same approach used by schema migration tools such as [alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/).   Using a real migration tool and just invoking "upgrade" instead of "create_all()" would be the best practice here.

comparing schemas is not a simple task - alembic actually includes a feature which provides this which you can also access at the API level, but it has many caveats and is more of a timesaver for when one is generating new migration scripts.

Edit: Alembic's api: [compare_metadata](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#alembic.autogenerate.compare_metadata)

example:

```
from alembic.migration import MigrationContext
from alembic.autogenerate import compare_metadata
from sqlalchemy.schema import SchemaItem
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeEngine
from sqlalchemy import (create_engine, MetaData, Column,
        Integer, String, Table)
import pprint

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

engine.execute('''
    create table foo (
        id integer not null primary key,
        old_data varchar,
        x integer
    )''')

engine.execute('''
    create table bar (
        data varchar
    )''')

metadata = MetaData()
Table('foo', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('data', Integer),
    Column('x', Integer, nullable=False)
)
Table('bat', metadata,
    Column('info', String)
)

mc = MigrationContext.configure(engine.connect())

diff = compare_metadata(mc, metadata)
pprint.pprint(diff, indent=2, width=20)
```

output:

```
[ ( 'add_table',
    Table('bat', MetaData(bind=None),
        Column('info', String(), table=<bat>), schema=None)),
  ( 'remove_table',
    Table(u'bar', MetaData(bind=None),
        Column(u'data', VARCHAR(), table=<bar>), schema=None)),
  ( 'add_column',
    None,
    'foo',
    Column('data', Integer(), table=<foo>)),
  ( 'remove_column',
    None,
    'foo',
    Column(u'old_data', VARCHAR(), table=None)),
  [ ( 'modify_nullable',
      None,
      'foo',
      u'x',
      { 'existing_server_default': None,
        'existing_type': INTEGER()},
      True,
      False)]]
```

Comment: Well, I know how to use alembic and consider it the duty of the programmer that whenever he changes the entities he also cares about db migration (which in my case would be a simple recreate of the db-schema). The point of my question therefore is not how to use migration tools but how to detect that entities changed compared to the db so that the dev would not need to care about migrations at all.

Comment: the feature in alembic does this, though many areas are not implemented or unreliable on some backends.  to do it fully and accurately (meaning: column types with arguments, constraints, defaults) is a very involved task, as the SQLAlchemy metadata construct only generates CREATE and DROP statements, which don't necessarily line up with what the database's system views report back.   post is edited.